# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.Long out of START ARRAY token

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I've been researching the problem but can't really find a solution for my case ...

I try to send a JSON array but I get this error, I have investigated the problem and I do not understand the problem 100% therefore I do not know where to attack it.

DETAILED ERROR

```
{
  "type" : "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message"

  "title" : "Bad Request",

  "status" : 400,

  "detail" : "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Long` out of START_ARRAY token; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Long` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 74] (through reference chain: com.curtipieles.app.service.dto.LeatherDTO[\"usageId\"])",
  "path" : "/api/leathers",
  "message" : "error.http.400"

}
```

PD: THE BACKEND IS GENERATED IN **JHIPSTER**

HERE MY DTO:

```
private Long usageId;
private Long colorId;
public Long getColorId() {
    return colorId;
}

public void setColorId(Long colorId) {
    this.colorId = colorId;
}

public String getColorName() {
    return colorName;
}

public void setColorName(String colorName) {
    this.colorName = colorName;
}


public Long getUsageId() {
    return usageId;
}

public void setUsageId(Long usageId) {
    this.usageId = usageId;
}

public String getUsageUsage() {
    return usageUsage;
}

public void setUsageUsage(String usageUsage) {
    this.usageUsage = usageUsage;
}
```

[JSON array I am trying to send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpBUt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an array of numbers for `usageId` field while it is defined as a `Long`. You must choose who is right: JSON payload (frontend) or java code (backend). Same for `colorId`.

If frontend is right, then change the declaration of your field in java backend:

```
private List<Long> colorId;
```

If backend is right, change your frontend code code so that it sends this JSON payload:

```
"colorId": 1234,
```

Comment: If the problem is in the front, how should I solve it? Since I am sending everything through a form

Comment: Well, JHipster has many examples in the project you generated. Are you beginning in Angular?

Comment: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Desktop/Devs/CURTIPIELES/curti-back/src/main/java/com/curtipieles/app/service/mapper/LeatherMapper.java:[26,13] Can't map property "java.util.List<java.lang.Long> colorI
d" to "com.curtipieles.app.domain.Color color". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "com.curtipieles.app.domain.Color map(java.util.List<java.lang.Long> value)". 
I get this error when making the change in the backend ...

Comment: You should edit your question rather than posting long comments that are difficult to read. It seems to me that you don't have a good understanding of all the technologies behind JHipster (Spring, JPA, Angular). This error shows that you made changes only in the DTO, so then the app fails when saving to database because MapStruct does not know how to map LeatherDTO to the Leather entity, if you fixed this then it would still be failing when saving to the database because you did not modify the Liquibase migration. Why don't update your JDL and re-generate entities?